# how to add image dynamically jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I used the following code to dynamically create an img, the div is created and works fine. So is the input text but the problem is that the img control is created but the img is not shown I can't find where the problem is help please.

```
$.each(data.user, function (i,data) {

    $("<div>"+data.id+"  </div>").attr('id',data.id).appendTo('#page_14_14');
    $('#'+data.id).css({"border-color": "#C1E0FF", 
                        "border-weight":"1px",
                        "margin-top":"10px",                    
                        "border-style":"solid"});

    var ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'text', name:'text', value:data.email , id:data.email, disabled:true }).addClass("text");
    $(ctrl).appendTo("#"+data.id); 
    $('#'+data.email).css({"border-color": "#C1E0FF", 
                           "width":"50px",
                           "margin-top":"10px",                    
                           "border-style":"solid"});

    var img = $('<img/>').attr({ className:"inline" , src:"/www/images/Arrow.png" }).addClass("img");

    $(img).appendTo("#"+data.id);        
});
```

i also used this for the following two methods for the  img but i had the same problem

```
 var img = $('<img/>', {"class" :"inline", src:"/www/images/Arrow.png"     });


 var img = $('<img class="inline" src="/www/images/bg.png" width="50px" height="50px"  />');
```

Comment: Check if the `src` set to the img is correct

Comment: i feel stupid it seems that the problem was in the src www is the default path i just changed it to /images/arrow.png and it worked

Comment: When I tried to create a fiddle for this, I also ran into problems trying to use `data.email` as an ID. jQuery doesn't like `$("#user@domain.com")`, you need to escape the `@`. I suggest you use something else as the ID for the `input` element.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a var with the img element as a string.

```
var img = '<img class="inline" src="/www/images/Arrow.png" width="50" height="50" />';
```

Then prepend it to the div.

```
$('#' + data.id).prepend(img);
```

Comment: What he's doing is actually better, using `$('<img />')` to create an element instead of relying on string being converted etc

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this will help you!

```
<ul id="imagesList">
  <li>No images found</li>
</ul>

$(function(){
            //load image array
            var images = {'image1':'assets/img/linkedin_30px.png','image2':'assets/img/twitter_30px.png'};
            $.each(images, function(){
               $('#imagesList').append('<li>' + this + '</li>'); 
            });
        });
```